# How do I integrate an MVC rest service with Spring Integration?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-integration

My goal is to use Spring Integration to control the flow between multiple systems and add some logging and monitoring.

One of the systems is a RESTful MVC service.  I read the Spring Integration document here: http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#http-inbound.  There is a line here that I don't understand:

> If you are running within a Spring MVC application, then the aforementioned explicit servlet definition is not necessary. In that case, the bean name for your gateway can be matched against the URL path just like a Spring MVC Controller bean.

Can someone provide an example of integrating a Spring MVC restful endpoint with Spring Integration?  Ideally it would be nice to reuse the mapping definitions in my Controller that I've already defined, but perhaps that isn't the intended use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The discussion there is to route HTTP requests to an http inbound gateway.

If you already have a Controller, simply inject a MessagingGateway to invoke your Spring Integration flow...

http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway

Comment: I guess this is assuming that they are in the same .war, correct?  If you were going to use spring integration in a standalone .war, would you just configure spring integration with an inbound and outbound http MessagingGateway and associated adapter?

Comment: No; currently, the http inbound adapter requires a web container (runs in a war). A number of options for supporting a stand-alone http adapter are being examined.

Comment: @GaryRussell I am no expert in Spring Integration, but wouldn't you agree that referring to a controller in the service-interface attribute of <int:gateway> doesn't look coherent (I am not saying this wouldn't work).

Comment: That's not what I said; following the referenced documentation, create an interface `Foo` that has an appropriate method on it; declare a `<gateway/>` with a `Foo` service-interface and inject the `Foo` proxy into the controller. The controller just knows it has a `Foo`; it knows nothing of the fact that the Foo is a gateway into the messaging system.